# select the most fitting road by sketching lines on the map

Tags: algorithm, graph, gis

I have a 2D road net data, which contains a lot of road points and the lines that link them.
I want to select a road(or several road) by drawing lines on the map, and the lines can be very inaccurate, I want to find the most fitting road. Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks.

========================================================================

**UPDATE**:

It's not a route searching problem, setting start point and end point and finding a best route.

What I want to do is, when user want to select a certain route on the map, he will draw a sketch line on the map like this:

[image]

and then the most fitting route can be found and highlighted like this:

[image]

Comment: Thats exactly what a router service does. Obviously a Router can be integrated in very different way with you data and your working environments. ESRIs Network analyst is an example which works with different data in your Desktop Environments (ArcGIS). GraphHopper would be another example which works mostly with OpenStreetmap data in any environment, but you need some coding to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but I know what you mean, it definitely can be solved with a router, because the vertices of the digitized line are nothing more than Via-points. So you don't search for the best route between A and B but for the only matching route to fit all your via-points (=vertices). I also have solved problems like this with Graphhopper, but as said, I needed a lot of programming to fit it into our Environment. Perhaps someone knows a better product which can be used out of the box.

Comment: Additional hint: before using the vertices as via-points for routing, the polyline should be generalized (reducing the vertices leads to reduction of subroutes). So thats why I ask you to clarify in which environment you plan to do all this. If this should be a web application, an example for a Generalization Tool would be [Simplify.js](http://mourner.github.io/simplify-js/)

Answer (score 0):

1) Find the roads that link together

2) assign cost from one road to another road link (only the ones that are touching)

3) Pick up the ones with lowest cost - recursively